# How to select an element of array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array in this format:

```
var array = [["one", "two", "three], ["four", "five", "six"], ["seven", "eight", "nine"]]
```

So, how can I select for example "four".

Comment: but I didn't found this case there

Comment: `array[1][0]` will return you 'four'. But to understand that you have to understand how arrays work, this is not Swift specific question.

Comment: @EricAya right, fixed answer, upvoted your comment.

Comment: This will help you array[1][0] . But its not proper . To do it dynamically you will need nested for loop.

Comment: As @EricAya mentioned, it is an array of arrays of strings, "four" is the first element at the second element of `array` means that it is: `array[1][0]`. Note that -as the guys mentioned- you should know how arrays work...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
let arrayOfArray:[[String]] = [["one", "two", "three"], ["four", "five", "six"], ["seven", "eight", "nine"]]
let middleArray = arrayOfArray[1]
let firstItem = middleArray[0]
let simplier = arrayOfArray[1][0]
```

And the result in storyboard
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The variable `array` is of type `Array of Array of String`

```
print(array[1]) //this will print second element of the array. which is ["four", "five", "six"]
```

and to access the first element in the second index use below.

```
print(array[1][0]) // this will print your desire output. "four"
```